# Is the set complete?

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Let $X=[1,\infty)$, and $d(x,y)=|\frac{1}{x} -\frac{1}{y}|$.

Is this set $X$ complete? Is it compact?

I have difficulty understanding what completeness really is. I know the defintion that within the complete set every Cauchy sequence converges. I am using Rudin's book, there it is specified as an example that the metric space of rational numbers with the distance function $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ is not complete. I do not understand this. If someone could address these questions I have, I would be grateful.

The distance function is always smaller than one. I assume the set is not compact because it is not bounded above? Or is it bounded by $1$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A necessary condition for compactness is the set to be totally bounded. Only bounded together with closedness is not enough in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that a set $X$ is complete, you have to take an arbitrary Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$ with elements in the set and do $3$ things:

1) search for a hypothetical $x$ which you expect to be the limit of $x_n$

2) check that this $x$ is indeed an element of the set $X$

3) prove that $d(x_n,x)\to 0$

For compactness in a metric space, it is enough to show that each sequence $\{x_n\}\subset X$ has a convergent subsequence with a limit again in the set $X$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please comment on the set X? I think given the distance function, the distance is always smaller than 1. Does this imply that the set is bounded?

Comment: Yes, it is bounded, but this doesn't help you for showing compactness. For  that it is not complete take the sequence $x_n=n$, as Ahmed. For that it is not compact, assume it was compact. But then it will be also complete, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I am still confused a bit. The definition lf cauchy sequence is that elements get close to each other. But if I take the elements to be 1,2,3,4,,...,n, then do they make a cauchy sequence? The distance remains the same, it doesnt change, or get smaller

Comment: Do not forget that you use the given metric $d(x,y)=|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}|$, and not the usual metric $|x-y|$. Then for the sequence $x_n=n$ you have $d(x_n,x_m)=|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}|\leq \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}\leq \frac{2}{n},\,\forall m>n$. So for $\epsilon>0$, chose $\frac{2}{n}\leq \epsilon$ and you will have that $d(x_n,x_m)\leq \epsilon,\,\forall n,m\ge \frac{2}{\epsilon}$

Comment: Oh god sorry. Thanks a lot for your time pal

Answer (score 1):

It is not complete because not every Cauchy sequence is convergent. Consider for instance $(x_n)$ defined by $x_n = n$.

Since compactness $\implies$ completeness, we deduce that it is also not compact.

Comment: I do not think not completeness implies compactness

Comment: @IdiotfromPrinceton I did not say that.

Comment: Ah I see now thank you